# calculation of the derivative for each line of a file with over 100 000 rows

Tags: linux, awk, scilab

I'm currently processing large files with values which look e.g. like this (always 2 columns, but over 100 000 rows):

1.3 1.5

2.5 2.0

3.6 6.0

4.0 10.1

7.8 11.5

For these files I want to calculate the derivative like: (2.0-1.5)/(2.5-1.3) & then (6.0-2.0)/(3.6-2.5) and so on.
I wrote a Scilab file which reads in the matrix x from the file (test.txt) and then does a for-loop where the derivatives are calculated. Here is my version:

```
[x] = read('test.txt',-1,2);

i = 1;

j = 1;

s = size(x);

for i = 1:s(1,1)-1

f(i) =  (x(i+1,2)-x(i,2))/(x(i+1,1)-x(i,1))

delta(i)=((x(i+1,1)+x(i,1)))/2

i=i+1

end
```

My questions are twofold:

1) the calculation for over 100 000 rows takes very long -> is there a possibility to do that quicker? Or is that only possible when the count of the rows is reduced (e.g. by only considering every 1000th step?)

2) Since I want to do that in a linux script: is there an easy way to do that in awk or with an other linux tool (like sed...)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Scilab you can proceed as follow

```
x = read('test.txt',-1,2);
f=diff(x(:,2))./diff(x(:,1))
delta=(x(2:$,1)+x(1:$-1,1))/2
```

Answer (score 4):

give this line a try:

```
awk '{if(NR>1)printf "%.1f\n",($2-b)/($1-a);a=$1;b=$2}' file
```

output with your example data:

```
0.4
3.6
10.3
0.4
```

If the result is not what you want, please provide an expected output example.